# NumPy: Find the maximum value from each row set it to 1 and rest as 0

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array as this,

```
array([[ 0.49596769,  1.15846407, -1.38944733],
       [-0.47042814, -0.07512128 , 1.90417981]], dtype=float32)
```

I want to find the maximum for each row and change it to 1 and rest as 0. Like this.

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]], dtype=float32)
```

What is the most efficient way to get it done using numpy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One approach would be -

```
(a == a.max(axis=1, keepdims=1)).astype(float)
```

Sample run -

```
In [43]: a
Out[43]: 
array([[ 0.49596769,  1.15846407, -1.38944733],
       [-0.47042814, -0.07512128,  1.90417981]])

In [44]: (a == a.max(axis=1, keepdims=1)).astype(float)
Out[44]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

---

If there are multiple ones in a row with the same maximum value and you would like to set only the first one as `1` -

```
idx = a.argmax(axis=1)
out = (idx[:,None] == np.arange(a.shape[1])).astype(float)
```

Sample run -

```
In [49]: a
Out[49]: 
array([[2, 4, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])

In [50]: (a == a.max(axis=1, keepdims=1)).astype(float)
Out[50]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])

In [51]: idx = a.argmax(axis=1)

In [52]: (idx[:,None] == np.arange(a.shape[1])).astype(float)
Out[52]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

For performance, we can have an initialization based approach -

```
def initialization_based(a): 
    idx = a.argmax(axis=1)
    out = np.zeros_like(a,dtype=float)
    out[np.arange(a.shape[0]), idx] = 1
    return out
```

Answer (score 0):

or with argsort:

```
 (a.argsort()==a.shape[1]-1).astype(int)
```

it will manage multiple maxs.

Comment: Think you need one more `argsort` there : `(a.argsort(1).argsort(1)==a.shape[1]-1).astype(int)`.